# ActiveMQ master slave failover loses messages

Tags: c++, activemq-classic, activemq-cpp

ActiveMQ is losing a lot of messages when failover is involved (only on topics).
The producer writes 1000 messages in the topic while (at the same time) the consumer is reading from the same topic. In the middle of the process, I close ActiveMQ master and the process is continued with the ActiveMQ slave. When the transition is made, a lot of messages are lost (~100 messages). The product I'm working on involves not losing messages.
What could I do for persistence on topics?
Producer:

```
#include <activemq\library\ActiveMQCPP.h>
#include <cms\Connection.h>
#include <cms\Session.h>
#include <activemq\core\ActiveMQConnection.h>
#include <activemq\core\ActiveMQConnectionFactory.h>
#include <activemq\core\ActiveMQSession.h>
#include <activemq\core\ActiveMQConsumer.h>
#include <activemq\core\ActiveMQQueueBrowser.h>
#include <activemq\core\PrefetchPolicy.h>
#include <activemq/core/policies/DefaultPrefetchPolicy.h>
#include <activemq\util\ActiveMQProperties.h>
#include <activemq\util\Config.h>
#include <decaf\util\Properties.h>
#include <cms\Queue.h>
#include <cms\Topic.h>
#include <cms\MapMessage.h>
#include <cms\MessageEnumeration.h>
#include <cms\CMSException.h>
#include <activemq\commands\Command.h>
#include <decaf\lang\Pointer.h>
#include <activemq\transport\Transport.h>
#include <activemq\transport\TransportFilter.h>
#include <activemq\commands\SessionInfo.h>
#include <activemq\commands\ActiveMQMessage.h>
#include <activemq\commands\BrokerInfo.h>

#include <activemq\exceptions\ConnectionFailedException.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <decaf\lang\Throwable.h>

std::string _amqURI("failover:(tcp://host1:61616,tcp://host2:61616)?initialReconnectDelay=5000&maxReconnectAttempts=2");
const std::string _username("user");
const std::string _password("pass");
const std::string _host("localhost");
const std::string _destination("Test.AMQ.bogcretu.Topic");

std::string _garbageMessage("GARBAGE0_GARBAGE1_GARBAGE2_GARBAGE3_GARBAGE4_GARBAGE5_GARBAGE6_GARBAGE7_GARBAGE8_GARBAGE9");
int _countMessages = 1000;
int _multiplyFactor = 100;
std::string _bodyMessage = "";

void CreateMessage()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _multiplyFactor; i++) {
        _bodyMessage += _garbageMessage;
    }
}

int main()
{
    activemq::library::ActiveMQCPP::initializeLibrary();
    CreateMessage();
    activemq::core::ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory;
    factory.setBrokerURI(_amqURI);
    std::auto_ptr<cms::TextMessage> message;
    std::auto_ptr<cms::Connection> connection(factory.createConnection(_username, _password));

    connection->start();

    std::auto_ptr<cms::Session> session(connection->createSession());
    std::auto_ptr<cms::Destination> destionation(session->createTopic(_destination));
    std::auto_ptr<cms::MessageProducer> producer(session->createProducer(destionation.get()));

    producer->setDeliveryMode(cms::DeliveryMode::PERSISTENT);

    for (int i = 0; i < _countMessages; i++) {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << i;
        std::string number = ss.str();
        message.reset(session->createTextMessage(number));
        producer->send(message.get());
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }

    //message.reset(session->createTextMessage("DONE"));
    //producer->send(message.get());

    //connection->close();

    //activemq::library::ActiveMQCPP::shutdownLibrary();

    return 0;
}
```

Consumer:

```
#include <activemq\library\ActiveMQCPP.h>
#include <cms\Connection.h>
#include <cms\Session.h>
#include <activemq\core\ActiveMQConnection.h>
#include <activemq\core\ActiveMQConnectionFactory.h>
#include <activemq\core\ActiveMQSession.h>
#include <activemq\core\ActiveMQConsumer.h>
#include <activemq\core\ActiveMQQueueBrowser.h>
#include <activemq\core\PrefetchPolicy.h>
#include <activemq/core/policies/DefaultPrefetchPolicy.h>
#include <activemq\util\ActiveMQProperties.h>
#include <activemq\util\Config.h>
#include <decaf\util\Properties.h>
#include <cms\Queue.h>
#include <cms\Topic.h>
#include <cms\MapMessage.h>
#include <cms\MessageEnumeration.h>
#include <cms\CMSException.h>
#include <cms\MessageListener.h>
#include <cms\Message.h>
#include <activemq\commands\Command.h>
#include <decaf\lang\Pointer.h>
#include <activemq\transport\Transport.h>
#include <activemq\transport\TransportFilter.h>
#include <activemq\commands\SessionInfo.h>
#include <activemq\commands\ActiveMQMessage.h>
#include <activemq\commands\BrokerInfo.h>

#include <activemq\exceptions\ConnectionFailedException.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <decaf\lang\Throwable.h>

std::string amqURI("failover:(tcp://host1:61616,tcp://host2:61616)?initialReconnectDelay=5000&maxReconnectAttempts=2");

class MsgListener : public cms::MessageListener
{
public:
    std::string _amqURI;
    cms::Connection *_connection;
    cms::Session* _session;
    cms::Destination* _destination;
    cms::MessageConsumer* _consumer;
    bool _sessionTransacted;
    bool _useTopic;

    MsgListener(std::string amqURI, bool sessionTransacted, bool useTopic = false) : _amqURI(amqURI), _sessionTransacted(sessionTransacted), _useTopic(useTopic), _connection(NULL), _session(NULL), _destination(NULL), _consumer(NULL)
    {
        this->_connection = cms::ConnectionFactory::createCMSConnectionFactory(this->_amqURI)->createConnection();
        this->_connection->start();

        /*if (this->_sessionTransacted == true) {
            this->_session = this->_connection->createSession(cms::Session::SESSION_TRANSACTED);
        }
        else {
            this->_session = this->_connection->createSession(cms::Session::AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        }*/

        this->_session = this->_connection->createSession(cms::Session::DUPS_OK_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        if (useTopic) {
            this->_destination = this->_session->createTopic("Test.AMQ.bogcretu.Topic");
        }
        else {
            this->_destination = this->_session->createQueue("Test.AMQ.bogcretu.Topic");
        }

        this->_consumer = this->_session->createConsumer(this->_destination);
        this->_consumer->setMessageListener(this);

        /*std::cout.flush();
        std::cerr.flush();*/


    }

    ~MsgListener()
    {

    }

    void onMessage(const cms::Message* CMSMessage)
    {
        static int count = 0;

        try
        {

            const cms::TextMessage* textMessage = dynamic_cast<const cms::TextMessage*> (CMSMessage);
            std::string text = "";
            if (textMessage != NULL) {
                text = textMessage->getText();
            }
            else {
                text = "NOT A TEXTMESSAGE!";

            }

            std::cout << "(" << count << ", " << text << ")" << std::endl;
            count++;

        }
        catch (cms::CMSException& e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (this->_sessionTransacted) {
            this->_session->commit();
        }

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    }
};

int main()
{
    activemq::library::ActiveMQCPP::initializeLibrary();
    MsgListener consumer(amqURI, true, true);
    while (true);
    //activemq::library::ActiveMQCPP::shutdownLibrary();
}
```

Consumer_durable:

```
#include <activemq\library\ActiveMQCPP.h>
#include <cms\Connection.h>
#include <cms\Session.h>
#include <activemq\core\ActiveMQConnection.h>
#include <activemq\core\ActiveMQConnectionFactory.h>
#include <activemq\core\ActiveMQSession.h>
#include <activemq\core\ActiveMQConsumer.h>
#include <activemq\core\ActiveMQQueueBrowser.h>
#include <activemq\core\PrefetchPolicy.h>
#include <activemq/core/policies/DefaultPrefetchPolicy.h>
#include <activemq\util\ActiveMQProperties.h>
#include <activemq\util\Config.h>
#include <decaf\util\Properties.h>
#include <cms\Queue.h>
#include <cms\Topic.h>
#include <cms\MapMessage.h>
#include <cms\MessageEnumeration.h>
#include <cms\CMSException.h>
#include <cms\MessageListener.h>
#include <cms\Message.h>
#include <activemq\commands\Command.h>
#include <decaf\lang\Pointer.h>
#include <activemq\transport\Transport.h>
#include <activemq\transport\TransportFilter.h>
#include <activemq\commands\SessionInfo.h>
#include <activemq\commands\ActiveMQMessage.h>
#include <activemq\commands\BrokerInfo.h>

#include <activemq\exceptions\ConnectionFailedException.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <decaf\lang\Throwable.h>

std::string amqURI("failover:(tcp://host1:61616,tcp://host2:61616)?initialReconnectDelay=5000&maxReconnectAttempts=2");

class MsgListener : public cms::MessageListener
{
public:
    std::string _amqURI;
    cms::Connection *_connection;
    cms::Session* _session;
    cms::Destination* _destination;
    cms::MessageConsumer* _consumer;
    bool _sessionTransacted;
    bool _useTopic;

    MsgListener(std::string amqURI, bool sessionTransacted, bool useTopic = false) : _amqURI(amqURI), _sessionTransacted(sessionTransacted), _useTopic(useTopic), _connection(NULL), _session(NULL), _destination(NULL), _consumer(NULL)
    {
        this->_connection = cms::ConnectionFactory::createCMSConnectionFactory(this->_amqURI)->createConnection();
        this->_connection->start();

        /*if (this->_sessionTransacted == true) {
            this->_session = this->_connection->createSession(cms::Session::SESSION_TRANSACTED);
        }
        else {
            this->_session = this->_connection->createSession(cms::Session::AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        }*/

        this->_session = this->_connection->createSession(cms::Session::DUPS_OK_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        if (useTopic) {
            this->_destination = this->_session->createTopic("Test.AMQ.bogcretu.Topic");
        }
        else {
            this->_destination = this->_session->createQueue("Test.AMQ.bogcretu.Topic");
        }

        //this->_consumer = this->_session->createConsumer(this->_destination);



        static const cms::Topic * topic = dynamic_cast<const cms::Topic*>(this->_destination);
        this->_consumer = this->_session->createDurableConsumer(topic, "sub_name", "");
        this->_consumer->setMessageListener(this);

        /*std::cout.flush();
        std::cerr.flush();*/


    }

    ~MsgListener()
    {

    }

    void onMessage(const cms::Message* CMSMessage)
    {
        static int count = 0;

        try
        {

            const cms::TextMessage* textMessage = dynamic_cast<const cms::TextMessage*> (CMSMessage);
            std::string text = "";
            if (textMessage != NULL) {
                text = textMessage->getText();
            }
            else {
                text = "NOT A TEXTMESSAGE!";
            }

            std::cout << "(" << count << ", " << text << ")" << std::endl;
            count++;

        }
        catch (cms::CMSException& e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (this->_sessionTransacted) {
            this->_session->commit();
        }

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    }
};

int main()
{
    activemq::library::ActiveMQCPP::initializeLibrary();
    MsgListener consumer(amqURI, true, true);
    while (true);
    //activemq::library::ActiveMQCPP::shutdownLibrary();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want message persistence then you should either be using Queues, or using Durable Topic subscriptions.  Topics on their own do not persist messages regardless of the persistent mode of the producer, in fact if there are no consumers subscribed and you send to a Topic the message is discarded, likewise the ActiveMQ configuration for controlling the constant pending message limit for Topics would discard old messages on a Topic where consumers can't keep up as a Topic has a low service assurance level.

You need to use a Queue and set persistent on the producer, or ensure that you have a pre-existing durable Topic subscription and send the messages using a producer that assigns the persistent flag if you want the message written to the store and recovered on broker failover.

Comment: I modified my code. I have to use a durable consumer instead of queues (so queues are not an option for the product). I've edited the question (added Consumer_durable). Right now the problem is that the listener is processing 100 messages and then nothing happens. I cut the connection (with the master). Then the listener process another 100 messages. The producer put in the topic all 1000 messages. I didn't find on ActiveMQ doc something about this. Is it normal?

Comment: You would need to do some debugging.  I don't see you setting a client ID on the connection would could be causing issues.  The C++ client code from ActiveMQ is not maintained so it could be a bug.  I'd try the Java client as it is still being maintained.

Comment: I've added clientID in the listener but the same thing is replicating, 100 messages are processed then stops. What I've seen is that the connection is restart (the master broker is closed) another 100 are read. And then do the same thing about 9 times => all those 1000 messages are read. Through "do the same thing" I mean to reopen the closed master broker which right now will be the slave (lock is acquired by the old slave broker) and close the new master broker. Do I need to bulk ACK or something like this? I didn't find anything about this behavior. PS: java is not an option :(